# Creating and writing multiple lines of text to a text file (CSV)?

Tags: swift, csv

I'm trying to create a way for a user to sign in and store their username and password in a text file. This is for a school project, so it's not stored securely and I don't think I'll have time to set up/learn how to serialize the data anyways. 
The main part I'm having issues with is trying to write the data as a CSV to later split the user's scores into an array based off of the data it received from the text file.

I've tried a different method of writing to the text file which was:
`writeString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.write(to: fileURL, options: Data.WritingOptions.withoutOverwriting)` But this didn't seem to work for me

```
struct UserAccount: Codable {
        var username: String
        var password: String
        var scores: [Int]
    }

var user = UserAccount(username: "", password: "", scores: [0])

func writeTextFile(_ user: UserAccount) {
    //Creating text file to read and write user's data (username, password, and score values)
    let fileName = "UserDataQuizApp"
    let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "UserDataQuizApp") {
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fileName)
        }
    } catch {print("error when deleting \(fileName)") }

    // If the directory was found, we write a file to it and read it back
    if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt") {
        print("The path is: \(fileURL)")

        do {
            try user.username.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            try ",".write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            try user.password.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            for i in 0 ... user.scores.count {
                try ",".write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                try String(user.scores[i]).write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Writing the array to the text file doesn't work at all right now because it says the index is out of range, but when I commented it out and tried to only write the username and password, only the password would be in the file when I checked it. I was expecting the username, a comma, and then the password to be in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for crash is in line `for i in 0 ... user.scores.count` it should be either `for i in 0 ..< user.scores.count` or `for score in user.scores`.

And you are trying to write each text to a file. 
That means only last `write(to:..` will have effect. Everything written will be overwritten.

To fix that, create a single string contains all info then write it to the file.
For eg the write function should be like :

```
func writeTextFile(_ user: UserAccount) {
        //Creating text file to read and write user's data (username, password, and score values)
        let fileName = "UserDataQuizApp"
        let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

        do {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "UserDataQuizApp") {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fileName)
            }
        } catch {print("error when deleting \(fileName)") }

        // If the directory was found, we write a file to it and read it back
        if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt") {
            print("The path is: \(fileURL)")

            do {
                var contents = [user.username, user.password]
                contents.append(contentsOf: user.scores.map { "\($0)"})
                let string = contents.joined(separator: ",")
                print("contents \(string)")
                try string.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            } catch {
                print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```